# Problema con UI de botones para diferentes elementos

Tags: css, firefox, chrome

Estoy maquetando unos botones, pero si uso por ejemplo un elemento *anchor* y un elemento *button* no presentan el mismo aspecto en diferentes navegadores (Chromium 84.0.4147.105 - Build oficial on Ubuntu / Moxilla Firefox 79.0 for Ubuntu).

Chromium aplica estilos de navegador y Firefox no, entonces en principio obtengo:

[image: imagen en Chromium]

en Chromium y el siguiente resultado en Firefox:

[image: imagen en Firefox]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <style>
        /*** reset ***/

        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            -moz-box-sizing   : border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin    : 0;
            padding   : 0;
            text-align: center
        }
        html {
            font-size: calc(5px+1vw)
        }


        /*** estilos botones ***/

        .btn {
            -moz-font-size: auto;
            font-size     : inherit;
            appearance    : button;


            background    : rgb(41, 40, 40);
            border        : 1px solid grey;
            border-radius : 3px;
            color         : white;
            cursor        : pointer;
            font-weight   : 600;
            padding       : 1rem;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background: grey; padding: 1rem;">

    <main>
        <a href="" class="btn">
            anchor
        </a>
        <button class="btn">
            button
        </button>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Las siguiente propiedades son las que están afectando a la visualización en uno u otro:

```
font-size  : inherit;
appearance : button;
```

`font-size : inherit;` en Chromium esta haciendo que ambos botones tengan el mismo tamaño, pero desigual en Firefox, si se quita es al contrario.
Probé `-moz-font-size: auto;` para tratar de corregirlo pero no es válido.

Luego la propiedad: `appearance : button;` se aplica en Chromium por el navegador a elementos de tipo `input` y `buttom` y es responsable de la separación entre los botones, que me resulta adecuada por lo que la he agregado para que aplique también a los botones *anchor*. Esta propiedad no funciona en Firefox.

Entonces **tengo dos problemas** entre navegadores:

- Tamaño desigual de ambos botones
- La separación entre ambos botones

El **resultado** que quisiera obtener es el de la primera imagen.

Answer (score 0):

Una propuesta de solución sería:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>

        /*** reset ***/

        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            -moz-box-sizing   : border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
            margin    : 0;
            padding   : 0;
            text-align: center
        }
        html {
            font-size: calc(5px+1vw);
        }


         /*** estilos botones ***/

        .btn {
            background    : rgb(41, 40, 40);
            border        : 1px solid grey;
            border-radius : 3px;
            color         : white;

            appearance        : button;
            cursor            : pointer;
            display           : inline-block;
            font-size         : inherit;
            font-weight       : 600;
            list-style        : none;
            padding           : 1rem;
            text-decoration   : none;
            vertical-align    : middle;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body style="background: grey; padding: 1rem;">

    <main>
        <a href="" class="btn">
            anchor
        </a>
        <button class="btn">
            button
        </button>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Aunque **no esta en la pregunta** (no me di cuenta al crear el ejemplo mínimo): *ambos botones presentan una fuente diferente*. ***Se debe indicar una fuente para el documento***, por ejemplo en el *reset*. Esto corrige el tamaño desigual.

***Otros estilos añadidos.***

> Corrige el problema de espaciado horizontal entre los botones *en Firefox*:

```
display: inline-block;
```

> Corrige posibles problemas con la alineación vertical de los botones:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```